# Move numbers up and down in vector

Tags: r, vector

I want to move data in a vector to test if it becomes linearly dependent of another data set. What I'm missing is an efficient way to do something like this.

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4)

v2 <- c(NA,v1[1:3])

v3 <- c(v1[2:4],NA)
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this:

```
v2 <- v1[NA,T,T,T]
```

Comment: Package `taRifx` has a `shift` function (`taRifx:::shift(v1, n = -1, pad = TRUE, wrap = FALSE)` for example). You also can have a look at `lag` function.

Comment: In what way is the first `v2` and `v3` "not efficient"? Do you mean efficiency in time, or in space, or in typing?

Comment: This is another possibility, `v222 <- v1[c(NA,1:3)]` but I think your original is actually more efficient in terms of execution time.

Comment: @MikeWise  I guess in terms of syntax, more than in execution time.

Comment: Well, will post mine as an answer then :). Just for kicks.

Comment: Have a look at `help("ccf")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
shift(v1, 0:1)
shift(v1, 0:1, type='lead')
```

Comment: @Mikkel No problem.  Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is this - which is in the spirt of what you are looking for:

```
v222 <- v1[c(NA,1:3)]
```

But I am guessing that the original is faster.

Comment: Yes that is about the same. To clarify i needed a way with less typing that worked in general if the numbers need to be moved further. Anyway i'm thankful for your answer and I'll be sure to clarify next time :D